# how to keep global namespace clean from third party lib

Tags: c++

I am doing zlib wrapper library on C++.

My header file with my zlib class looks like this:

```
#include <zlib.h>

class ZLibCompressor{
protected:
    z_stream zs;
};
```

I can implement everything in the object file, however I need to have `z_stream` inside the class as class member.

In order to have access to it, I need to include "zlib.h".

If I include "zlib.h", it will "pollute" global namespace with lots of constants and so on, such Z_OK and many others.

The only solution I can imagine is pimpl like `void *` to allocated `z_stream`.

However if I do this, my code will get extra slow and the only reason I want this member to be in the class is exactly the better performance I can get of reusing the `z_stream` handle.

Comment: Is `z_stream*` good enough (and a forward declaration)? Also, you can use `pImpl` idiom.

Comment: z_stream * is good, but I still need to have dynamic allocation, do I ?

Comment: I would use a `void*` member, allocate a `z_stream` in the .cpp and then `delete reinterpret_cast<z_stream*>(member);` I don't see a way to do this without dynamic allocation. Maybe wait for C++20 and modules, which fixes this...

Comment: :) they wont fix it because it is C library I interface with.

Comment: @Nick - yes, you will need a dynamic allocation in both cases - `pImpl` and `z_stream*`. This will be only in the constructor/destructor of the object.

Comment: Thanks Kiril. This was what I thought too. Except some crazy ideas with factory pattern + vector<z_stream>

Comment: `Z_OK` is a macro, it doesn't pollute the global namespace, it pollutes _all_ namespaces. Macros don't respect any scope, they replace anything and everything that matches. There's not much you can do about that unless you redefine the whole `zlib.h` API by hand.

Comment: _"my code will get extra slow"_ - because a few functions won't be inlined? That seems unlikely to make anything "extra slow".

Comment: On my system `z_stream` is a `typedef` so it can't be forward declared (unless its basic type is part of the `API` - not sure if it is).

Comment: @JonathanWakely - well it depends how you look at it. Call new / delete is not cheap operation. About Z_OK - exactly my point.

Comment: I doubt if allocation would be a noticeable overhead compared with compressing and decompressing the data tbh. But if you absolutely had to you could get creative with *placement new* to avoid it.

Comment: placement new is nice idea, but how i cam manage the size in a good portable way?

Comment: @Nick Only thing I can think of is a `static_assert` to check the size of `z_stream` to warn people if the `zlib` version is incompatible with whatever size you allocated in your library for the *placement*.

Comment: @Galik this is what i thought as well. but probably i will do it with bigger buffer so there will be no probl for next versions